# Gradle private repository for dependencies

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

I am using Gradle for my project and yesterday I faced issues while building project since https://plugins.gradle.org was not working. So is there any way to clone dependencies & plugins to AWS S3/Artifactory/Nexus during the build process and if I face an outage issue for public repos like Maven or Gradle I should be able to serve project dependencies & plugin via AWS S3/Artifactory/Nexus

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a maven project you can just go the the .xml file and add it as a dependencie which you'll find in the maven repository :https://mvnrepository.com/

Comment: thanks @YourHelper, I am using Gradle and I am not sure if you understood my question correctly